# I want to input numbers between 1 and 15 into the text field

Tags: java, textbox

How do you validate a text field so that it can only accept number between 1 and 15? I want to input numbers between 1 and 15 into the text field.

Comment: Parse the text into a number and check the value or use a regex.

Answer (score 1):

If you're use GUI design mode, you can add event `KeyReleased` to the `jTextField`

You can find out `properties` window to set the event up in `design` page

and do like

```
private void jTextField1KeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt)
{                                     
    try
    {
        int number = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText()); //parse String to int
        if( number>15 || number <1 )
        {
            /* do something if the number isn't between 1~15 */
            jTextField1.setText("");
        }
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e)
    {
        /* do something if it isn't a number in text field */
        jTextField1.setText("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try : input tag with type="number" 
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_min.asp

```
<input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="15">
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="15">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of consume() with KeyTyped event which helps you to accept only numbers. Later go for range operation from Generated input.
Below is the code for accepting only numbers from keyboard-

```
char c=evt.getKeyChar();

if(Character.isAlphabetic(c))

   evt.consume();

//Go for range operation here.
```